# opening a jpg file in python

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

```
from PIL import Image
import cv2 #EDIT, this line added

im = Image.open('withmed.jpg',0)
im.show('image',img)
k = cv2.waitkey(0)
if k == 27:
    cv2.destroyAll windows
```

I am trying to  open a jpg image which is saved in desktop. but on running this piece of code an error is popping out

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anusha/aswathy.py", line 5, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('image',img)
    error: /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.8+dfsg1/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:269: 
    error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function imshow
```

Comment: Check case of characters in filename? Full source (without simplifications) and tracestack may help us to figure out the error.

Comment: You need to include absolute path in place of `(path of the image)` Or show us what path have you give as parameter of `Image.open`  ?

Comment: i have edited the code and the error now it showing is "size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function imshow"

Comment: Could you adjust your question and show us the full error stacktrace (if any)? This can help greatly in debugging.

Comment: question is edited with the error.

Comment: I'm not versed in OpenCV, but I do know it will throw this exact error when either the image cannot be found (wrong permission, wrong path, ...) or the image type is not supported (less likely). Just a wild guess, but did you install the necessary  `dev` packages for the image types you wish to support before compiling/installing `Pillow` or `OpenCV`? You might also put a few `try/except` statements in your code...to see if it can find the image at all, for example.

Comment: Instead of im = Image.open('withmed.jpg',0), try im = Image.open('withmed.jpg'). If that doesn't work, put print(im) afterwards and tell us what it says.

Comment: @Hugo thanks it worked...im = Image.open('withmed.jpg')was the rite statement

Comment: @Aswathy: Great, I've added it as an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27485531/724176) if you'd like to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
im = Image.open('withmed.jpg',0)
```

try:

```
im = Image.open('withmed.jpg')
```

If that doesn't work, put `print(im)` afterwards and tell us what it says.

Answer (score 0):

As well as PIL, image io, OpenCV and skimage are also powerful tools, with different applications each.
Especially if you want to work with the image and use machine learning, imageio is efficient.
For image io:

```
import imageio.v3 as iio
im = iio.imread('withmed.png')
```

And for skimage:

```
from skimage import io
im = io.imread('withmed.png')
```

and for OpenCV:

```
import cv2 as cv
cv.imread('withmed.png')
```

One important thing to know is that the types of output are different, while the output of opencv, skimage and imageio are numpy arrays, the output of PIL is an image class file: "PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile".